# pyomo - pass time limit to NEOS

Tags: pyomo

I am sending a pretty complex Pyomo MINLP to NEOS using Couenne.  I'm getting an error message that the solve time is too long (sorry, I don't have it still in Ipython).  Is there a way to set a max time and return the best feasible result?  I was able to get solutions back prior to adding my last set of constraints.  Current code is:

```
# model building...

solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
solver_manager.options['time_limit'] = 60*2
results = solver_manager.solve(model , opt='couenne',load_solutions=True,tee=True)
model.solutions.store_to(results)
results.write()
```